# Matching Xcode color space with Digital Color Meter

Tags: xcode, colors, interface-builder, rgb

In Xcode Interface Builder, I use Digital Color Meter to find the color code of an item as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWrh0.png

The values for `(R,G,B)` are `(255,172,40)`.

Then I select a label to set it's color same. I proceed as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C45nV.png

However, now when I use Digital Color Meter to detect the newly assigned color, I find instead of `(255,172,40)`, I get `(253,156,32)`.

`[same domain as above]/X4yN4qw.png`  (unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to post another link)

How can I make the color of both items match?

Answer (score 2):

In Digital Color Meter, make sure that the display drop-down menu is set to "Display in Generic RGB." If using Interface Builder, set the color to be displayed in sRGB.