# UIColor setted is wrong when checked with color picker on screenshot

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I create a UIView with a hex UIColor of `#30CDD7` but when I check the screenshot of my screen in picker it shows `#34d5df`

This is the screenshot where I set the UIColor of the UIView

[image]

And this is the screenshot of the UIViewController of my app where the view is in

[image]

It all occurred in all of my UIViewController

Our designer was complaining because of the wrong colour.

Is there's a way to handle it?

I use swift if it needs a code to fix it.

Comment: As far as I know that, in the screenshot the color value will be different.
If you have simulator screenshot, or device screenshot are having differ color.

Comment: I guess its a dupplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788942/matching-xcode-color-space-with-digital-color-meter

Comment: Most likely differences in Color Spaces, interface builder is using sRBG

Comment: @MohyG both question and answer are focused on Digital Color Meter, my question was in any color picker, like photoshop or chrome color picker extensions

Comment: @dakota is there a fix in it?

Comment: Whichever color picker you're using, try to change color profile to match Xcode one (on your screenshot its that grey gear icon next to the "RGB Sliders")